# Difference between YAJSW (Yet Another Service Wrapper) and NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)

Tags: nsis, yajsw

I was researching for converting my Spring-Boot application into windows service, i was recommended to use either YAJSW or NSIS, can anyone please explain the difference between two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS is mainly a installer utility for other applications. While it does have some plug-ins for installing/starting/stopping services, it cannot be used to create a "Java application as a service" per se. You could use it as a generic Java application launcher and let the Java application itself call the service functions but it is probably a better idea to just use tools specifically built for this task.